# Verify the existence of an array of root nodes with JSONpath

Tags: java, json, rest, hamcrest

From the below JSON response, I can verify that a root node exists the in JSONpath using this method from hamcrest library:

```
assertThat(json, hasJsonPath("$.tool"));
```

This checks that the root node called 'tool' exists.

```
{
    "tool": 
    {
        "jsonpath": 
        {
            "creator": 
            {
                "name": "Jayway Inc.",
                "location": 
                [
                    "Malmo",
                    "San Francisco",
                    "Helsingborg"
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    "book": 
    [
        {
            "title": "Beginning JSON",
            "price": 49.99
        },

        {
            "title": "JSON at Work",
            "price": 29.99
        }
    ]
}
```

If I want to check the existence of the two root nodes (tool and book)using an array stored in a variable, how can this be achieved? I am not concerned about their values or the values of the sub nodes. I just want to verify that those 2 root nodes exist in the response and are valid paths.

After stringing my API response in a 'json' variable I tried something like this:

```
JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(json);

String[] rootNodes = {"tool", "book"};
assertThat(json, hasJsonPath(json.getString(rootNodes)));
```

But compiler was unhappy with the `getString` method.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root node operator is `$` so you can just read `$` into a map and that map will be keyed on your root node names.

For example:

```
// Approach 1
Map<String, Object> read = JsonPath.read(json, "$");

assertThat(read.size(), is(2));

assertThat(read.keySet(), hasItem("tool"));
assertThat(read.keySet(), hasItem("book"));

// Approach 2: if you want a String[] then ...
String[] rootNodeNames = read.keySet().toArray(new String[read.size()]);
assertThat(rootNodeNames, Matchers.both(arrayWithSize(2)).and(arrayContainingInAnyOrder("book", "tool")));

// Approach 3: if you want to hide it all behind the hasJsonPath() matcher
// note: each of these assertion will cause your JSON string to be parsed 
// so it's more efficient to do that once and assert against the 
// resulting map as I did above
assertThat(json, hasJsonPath("$", Matchers.hasKey("tool")));
assertThat(json, hasJsonPath("$", Matchers.hasKey("book")));
```

Comment: I printed $ to console and can see that values of the root nodes were also returned. I was looking to only extract the root nodes without their values, using some kind of array method. Btw, what library will add the 'is' method to the project? It's throwing an error

Comment: If the purpose here is to verify that there are two root nodes and that the names of these root nodes are: "tool" and "book" then the above code does exactly that. You don't _need_ to extract the root node names into a String[]  in order  to make that assertion. Re your other question: the fully qualified path to `is` is `org.hamcrest.Matchers` i.e. it is provided by the same class as `hasItem`.

Comment: I have updated the question showing how to extract the root node names into a `String[]` and showing how to hide the entire matcher inside a `hasJsonPath` call.

Comment: Fantastic, @glytching. I am beginning to see some interesting results after I added the correct hamcrest class to your snippet. I can now see an extraction of the root nodes without their values. If I want to verify that the root nodes are not null or empty without actually extracting their values, can this be achieved?

Comment: Regardless of what assertion you perform, it all starts with parsing the JSON and this results in the node names **and** values being deserialised. You can't deserilaise just the node names because `JsonPath `will always deserialise the entire JSON string. I think you should concentrate on your assertions without worrying about whether JsonPath has (redundantly, from your perspective) deserialised the values too. The above answer shows you three ways of asserting against the root nodes and completely ignores the values.

Comment: Beautiful answer. Plus one point for the additional approaches given. Can the array "rootNodeNames" be checked for nullness or emptiness (i.e not null or empty) with a line of code?

Comment: I have updated the answer to cover non zero and the array contents in a one liner. This also - implicity - covers the `null` condition.

Comment: how do I perform a one-liner assertion that a node has multiple values e.g  "book" contains "title": "Beginning JSON", and  "price": 49.99?

Comment: Use JsonPath's [Filter Predicates](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-predicates) to combine two predicates.